# SharePoint 2010: Set field value from query triggered by choice box selection

Tags: sharepoint, forms, infopath, field, sharepoint-2010

How do you link a form field to a choicebox selection so that the field's value is set by the information referenced by the ID of the choicebox selection? I have a choicebox in a custom list form which is bound to a "Client" list which contains client names, IDs, reference numbers, addresses, etc. The choicebox displays the client name and has the selected value set to ID. I would then like to query the Client list by the selected ID to populate form fields with Client Name, Client Address, Client Phone, etc. Is there a way to do this without using custom code? I am using SharePoint 2010, SharePoint Designer 2010 and InfoPath for the forms.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling this is not supported, but I was able to get this working by creating fields as follows in the [schema.xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms459356.aspx) of my custom list template:

```
<Field ID="{AB09A2D6-EBD4-4511-AE91-A8C54DC8442F}"
    Type="Lookup"
    Name="CustomItemIdLookup"
    DisplayName="Client"
    List="$Resources:core,lists_Folder;/Client"
    ShowField="Title"
    Hidden="FALSE"
    Required="TRUE"
    StaticName="CustomItemIdLookup">
</Field>
<Field ID="{E558933C-A03B-4932-85C9-6A786396AA78}"
    Type="Lookup"
    Name="CustomClientNameLookup"
    DisplayName="Client Name"
    List="$Resources:core,lists_Folder;/Client"
    ShowField="CustomClientName"
    Hidden="FALSE"
    JoinColName="tp_ID"
    JoinRowOrdinal="0"
    JoinType="INNER"
    FieldRef="CustomItemIdLookup"
    ReadOnly="FALSE"
    ShowInNewForm="FALSE"
    ShowInEditForm="FALSE">
</Field>
<Field ID="{5292CB52-80C7-4AFA-BA3E-93FDF22B37E3}"
    Type="Lookup"
    Name="CustomClientAddressLookup"
    DisplayName="Client Address"
    List="$Resources:core,lists_Folder;/Client"
    ShowField="CustomClientAddress"
    Hidden="FALSE"
    JoinColName="tp_ID"
    JoinRowOrdinal="0"
    JoinType="INNER"
    FieldRef="CustomItemIdLookup"
    ReadOnly="FALSE"
    ShowInNewForm="FALSE"
    ShowInEditForm="FALSE">
</Field>
<Field ID="{B3E22803-9A4B-4E7E-B05F-82221C182735}"
    Type="Lookup"
    Name="CustomClientPhoneLookup"
    DisplayName="Client Phone"
    List="$Resources:core,lists_Folder;/Client"
    ShowField="CustomClientPhone"
    Hidden="FALSE"
    JoinColName="tp_ID"
    JoinRowOrdinal="0"
    JoinType="INNER"
    FieldRef="CustomItemIdLookup"
    ReadOnly="FALSE"
    ShowInNewForm="FALSE"
    ShowInEditForm="FALSE">
</Field>
```

Note, Client Name, Client Address, Client Phone will not be editable and rich text/multiline fields do not work.