# SharePoint 2007: Custom Lookup columns

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I would create two separate lists, and have the data entered in list 1 populate some of the data columns in table 2. Example: Request Name (single line of text), Description (Multi lines of text), Type of Request (Choice), and Completion Date (date).

When I go to the second list, I select 'Lookup', then 'Get information from:', select the first list, and all I see are "ID", "Content Type", "Version" and the "Title".

What do I need to do to get the columns from list 1 to appear in the 'Lookup' section of table 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lookup field will only use text columns (regular text, calculated field with output type of text and computed columns that output text). You could probably fill out the additional fields by the means of a simple SharePoint Designer workflow that will run on item creation in the second list and fill out the columns.

Comment: I am going to create single line text items, then use those as the join the two lists.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to do this by creating a Feature with a custom List Definition using the FieldRef, JoinColName, JoinRowOrdinal, and JoinType attributes.

For more information, see [SharePoint 2010: Set field value from query triggered by choice box selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443551/sharepoint-2010-set-field-value-from-query-triggered-by-choice-box-selection).

Answer (score -1):

I think programming will be needed you will have to use something like smartpart and create your own asp.net control that will read from database and show the data as you need it